# Get ServletContext from MessageContext in interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

How can I get an object of ServletContext from the MessageContext supplied in an interceptor?
The TODO below is suppose to be a ServletContext.

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception {

    WebApplicationContext applicationContext =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(TODO);
            TestIdentitiesService service = applicationContext.getBean(TestIdentitiesService.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext context;

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
        throws Exception {

    WebApplicationContext applicationContext =
            WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
    TestIdentitiesService service =
    applicationContext.getBean(TestIdentitiesService.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a ServletContext with the following:

```
messageContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETCONTEXT);
```

Comment: The properties object on MessageContext is empty so it doesnt work.